# How do I apply the hover effect to a specific button

Tags: html, css, button

My hover style on a bootstrap button comes into effect when my mouse is over divs in the same row but I want it only when my mouse is over the specific div.

Comment: It's best if you share the current state of your code so that one could build on that to better answer your question.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!, unfortunately this question does not provide any codes so its not possible for us to help you with this, create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and show us what problems you are facing while attempting to do this, And also don't forget to review the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of stackoverflow for tips on how to ask a good question and what type of questions are [well suited](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for the site

Comment: Please add minimal reproducible example (in this case, your HTML, CSS and/or JS code)

Answer (score 0):

**Make a `class` or make a `ID` and call them where it needed.**

*I think this will work for you*.

```css
     .hdiv:hover , .btn:hover{ 
            background-color: red;
            color:white;
        }
      button{
              background-color:blue;
                color:white;
             }
        div{
            width: 500px;
          padding: 40px;
         
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
   
    <div>
        <p>hover nothing happens in this div</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="hdiv">
        <p>color changes on Hover in this div </p>
        <button class="btn">Hover Me too</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Let me know if this will work for you.**

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this

```
.specific-div:hover .btn:hover {
  background: red;
  color: white
}
```

Comment: This is not the correct way to write two classes in ```CSS``` it should be like this     ```.specific-div:hover, .btn:hover``` you need to separate two ```CSS``` classes with ```,```  this.